# How to exclude Test methods from automatic execution with NCrunch

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

This question is probably attributed to my blindness, but I failed to find a way how to **exclude certain test methods from being automatically executed by NCrunch**. There has to be an attribute or a similar means. I googled and searched the NCrunch website.

We are using VS.NET 2010, MS Test, R# (the tests should *not* be excluded from a run "All tests in solution" command).

The reason for excluding certain tests is that they eat too many resources or change data. I know I could use mocking frameworks in order to avoid the latter, but that's not the point here (and not possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

afaik you can right click the test(s) in the NCrunch Tests window and 'Ignore' them.

This adds lines in the [Projectname].crunchproject.local.xml in your project folder

```
  <IgnoredTests>
    <NamedTestSelector>
      <TestName>XXXTests.YYYTest.Name_of_the_TestMethod</TestName>
    </NamedTestSelector>
  </IgnoredTests>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. I didn't find this because I've been looking for 'exclude' rather than 'ignore' in Google and the help docs.